# Calculating the height of a CSS 3D rotationX transform

Tags: css, math, 3d, css-transforms

I'd like to find out the height of an element, of a specific width and height, after a rotationX transform has been applied to it.

Would be ideal to be able find out the angle of an element's rotationX transform given the desired height.

Answer (score 0):

`rotateX()` preserves the x-coordinate. The y-coordinate scales with the cosine of the rotation angle:

```
new_height = old_height * cos(angle)
```

The other way around is:

```
angle = arc cos(new_height / old_height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found 2 ways on finding dimensions of a DOM element after css 3D transforms have been applied to it.

1.By using `element.getBoundingClientRect()` which will return a `ClientRect` object with the correct dimensions of an elements after the transforms has been applied to it

```
   {
       bottom: 90.07061767578125
       height: 90.07061767578125
       left: 0
       right: 891
       top: 0
       width: 891
    }
```

2. A module called [domvertices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/domvertices) will return the `xyz` positions of 4 corner vertices for a DOM element, accounting for any transformatons:

   {
       a: {x: , y: , z: },
       b: {x: , y: , z: },
       c: {x: , y: , z: },
       d: {x: , y: , z: }
   }